# How do high-voltage DC/DC converters power themselves?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage

For example, a [600 V DC/DC converter](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/685/ds_BCM4414xG0F4440yzz-1129834.pdf) is powered only from its HV input, yet it somehow can run its internal electronics (I guess 3.3 V or something like that). Do they use a small DC/DC converter for this? How would that small converter work?

Answer (score 3):

Once common method uses a depletion mode (normally "on") FET connected to the high voltage to start the controller, then an auxiliary winding on the main transformer (for isolated topologies) starts up a "housekeeping" supply and shuts off the FET to keep power dissipation down. Then the control circuitry runs from the low voltage housekeeping supply.

Alternately a large value resistor and zener can provide a trickle current to start the controller, which then runs off of the aux winding after it's up and running. Not as power efficient as the depletion FET though.

Comment: This; some even integrate the FET/resistor, either on a separate pin, or tapping off the internal switch drain pin itself (see LNK623 and friends for example).  Small ones can even be entirely self-powered this way since the control current is so small (the LNKs can be used this way).